# PerspectiveQuadraticCost in PyDrake, solving with MOSEK

Tags: python, optimization, drake

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem that uses the `PerspectiveQuadraticCost` function defined in Drake. According to a 2022 paper "Motion Planning Around Obstacles with Convex Optimization", a perspective quadratic cost term can capture the cost

`\frac{||\dot{r}_i||_2^2}{\dot{h}_i}`

which is convex, if `\dot{h}_i > 0`. I see in the code GCS code base;
https://github.com/mpetersen94/gcs
that this is implemented using the PerspectiveQuadraticConstraint and solved with the MOSEK solver. I am assuming it is therefore that MOSEK is one of the solvers which considers this as a convex constraint (the `PerspectiveQuadraticCost` documentation mentions that 'most' solvers consider it as non-convex).

My problem arises when I wish to do something similar, but not on the GCS class structure (consisting of edges etc.). It seems `MathematicalProgram` does not have any member functions associated of the form `AddPerspectiveQuadraticCost` and `prog.AddCost(PerspectiveQuadraticCost,vars)` gives a non-supported `GenericCost` error.
The code in GCS assigns a cost to an edge according to

```
H = np.vstack(((self.order) * b_ctrl, np.matmul(np.sqrt(weight_matrix), A_ctrl)))
energy_cost = PerspectiveQuadraticCost(H, np.zeros(H.shape[0]))
self.edge_costs.append(energy_cost)

for edge in self.gcs.Edges():
    if edge.u() == self.source:
       continue
    edge.AddCost(Binding[Cost](energy_cost, edge.xu()))
```

which seems to be allowed (I run the code successfully). My example is as

```
H = np.stack(((self.order)*b_ctrl[0], weight*A_ctrl[0]))
energy_cost = PerspectiveQuadraticCost(H, np.zeros(H.shape)
self.prog.AddCost(energy_cost,self.rh_var_flat)
```

My question: How can I add a `PerspectiveQuadraticCost` to my problem without using any of the GCS base-code (edges, convex sets)? Is this currently supported? If not, is there a specific workaround?

An additional peculiarity, which might be connected in some way, is that the `L2NormCost` seems to not have been implemented for MOSEK (it throws the error `ValueError: MosekSolver is unable to solve because a L2NormCost was declared but is not supported.`) after invoking `self.prog.AddL2NormCost()`. However, also in the GCS code, this cost term is assigned to the edges of the graph via the Binding mentioned above.

update: it seems to be working with the SnoptSolver(), yet I need to introduce some binary variables, which is why I want to use MosekSolveR()

Thank you in advance for any help you could provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, Mosek (and other convex solvers) do not know how to consume these directly. You have to rewrite them using slack variables.  I have a [method in the GCS implementation](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/c7289e0c0c90bbde4b98aef13daed38f0f6bdb1a/geometry/optimization/graph_of_convex_sets.cc#L1348) which does exactly this, with a TODO to move it to the public API.  I agree it would be useful.

In the short term, you would need to implement the objectives using slack variables and constraints yourself.